# U-Sub in Integration

Tags: calculus, integration

I was solving the integral $\int (\frac{5}{2}(\sin{4x})-7)dx$ from $0$ to $t$ by substitution $u=4x$ when I began to wonder why the whole equation is effected by this substitution. What I mean is why do we replace the whole $dx$ at the end with it's $du$ equivalent? Since we can add derivatives, shouldn't the $u$ only effect the sin(4x) part of the integral?

Thank you!
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...why do we replace the whole dx at the end with it's du equivalent?

If you substitute $u=4x$, then $du=4dx$ and they are **not** equivalent. They only vary by a constant but they are definitely not the same!